# Provide A Programmer Bookshelf With Your CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I like how [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) has a few unique fields that are quite specific for developers. I think that's a great idea and thought about another addition:

If you search the blogosphere it's quite common to see developers promote/display their programming book collection. I think it would be an interesting add-on to the careers website for devs to attach their favourite books to their CV. I know for a fact that I would weigh and applicant who has read **"The Pragmatic Programmer"** a lot higher than someone who has a lot of "Learn X in 24 hours".

The statistical interest would be interesting as well to see if there's any correlation with certain books and the type of jobs they get. I would be curious to see how many that read **"Peopleware"** get managerial jobs, and would also reflect favorably for that employer.

Comment: I love this idea.

Comment: Eh, I tend not to read books like peopleware - I just wait for Jeff to summarize them on codinghorror.

Comment: should the Bookshelf also be part of a user's profile, so even stackoverflow users without a CV can have a bookshelf?  (And the bookshelf can be seen for users with hidden CVs)

Comment: Didn't know that the feature came from this question :)

Answer (score 26):

Fantastic idea, perhaps we can include some form of ISBN auto-lookup as well.

Comment: and perhaps the ability construct referral links using affiliate codes that the profile creator submits.

Comment: should this be on careers or on the profile page of stackoverflow?  (or both)

Comment: You could probably reuse some code from your Amazon ads experiment to auto insert images of the books.

Answer (score 13):

How about including support for those of us who have also written books?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I've just read too much, but this seems kinda silly to me: I've read "The Mythical Man Month".. doesn't mean I want to tell potential employers I have (though, in this case, I would).

I have "for Dummies" books alongside deep-dice assembly texts - neither indicates a greater or lesser degree of knowledge.

Likewise, I have books I've never read (and probably won't because my interests have changed, or they're too dated, etc) - some of those *would* "look" good, but if I haven't read them, it doesn't mean I'm any less of a dev/admin/etc.

I read *Applied Cryptography* (2d Ed) the week after I got it for my birthday - when I was 15 (the year it was published). Does that make me any better than someone who has never heard of it?

Comment: It's just another dimension employers can use in their determination. And as applicants, we can pick and choose what we want them to see (as we can with everything else in the CV).

Comment: I agree - it just seems like this would be a LOT easier to "fib" on

Answer (score 3):

Most of the books I read about programming were out of print 20 years ago.  Now I just look up APIs on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, and while I'm certain it will be gamed the employers can follow up in interviews if they really did base some of their selection criteria on the bookshelf listed.

The more creative programmers will list unusual off-the-beaten-path books that may pique an employer's interest.

"So, Adam, tell me how the Harry Potter series has improved your programming skills?"

"Well, the on-the-surface correlations are obvious, many people view programming as a..."

Comment: The word is "pique", not "peek".

Comment: You are *so* right.  When writing this I paused at that thought for several seconds because the correct word escaped me, and decided to write it incorrectly, figuring it would either come to me later, or someone would call me on it.  Thanks!

Comment: Harry Potter? Off-the-beaten-path? I thought the entire world, except me, had read them. ;)