# Will flagging a comment as obsolete harm a user?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags

Sometimes a comment is valid, but then the user makes the requested correction leading to the comment becoming obsolete. If I flag the comment as obsolete, will that harm the user in any way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, why would it?

The obsolete comment will disappear (if other users flag it or a moderator agrees with your flag), and that's about it. The only comment flag that may "hurt" the user is the "rude or offensive" one, depending on the circumstances it might lead to a suspension. But "obsolete" is absolutely harmless.

Comment: Even “rude or offensive” is unlikely to “harm” the user. If the comment is automatically deleted from having enough flags, the flag reason doesn't matter. If the flag is seen by a moderator, any action taken by the moderator would be based on the content of the comment (and probably on other aspects of the user's behavior), not by the choice of flag on the comment.

Comment: @Gilles That's why I put hurt in quotes, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: True, I suspect great many of my comments here get deleted over the time and I am not even aware of that.

Answer (score 10):

No, it will not. Users with many deleted comments are still allowed to comment, ask questions, or answer.

If you flagged the comment as obsolete, and the moderator who handled the flag noticed it was another offensive comment from that user, that would be different.

Comment: I think that in 99% of the cases no moderator is involved - enough flags and the comment get auto deleted.

Comment: That is not the point; even in the case a moderator is involved in 1% of the cases, a flag for an obsolete comment could have consequences for the user who wrote it, if the comment was more than just an obsolete comment, and the moderator notices that. ("It's the 100th comment from UnknownUser1233343434 who says idiots to the other users.")