# careers doesn't allow images in markdown or preview broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I wanted to add a ["Programmer Bookshelf"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26345/provide-a-programmer-bookshelf-with-your-cv) section to my CV but neither

```
[![alt desc][1][2]]

  [1]: image url
  [2]: amazon link

 or 

 <a href="amazon link"><img alt="alt desc" src="image url"></a>
```

Work when saved, despite working in the live preview

**Update:**

I currently have the following in my Background section:

```
<a href="http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer"><img alt="The Pragmatic Programmer" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41HXiIojloL._SY185.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/ASIN/0201485672"><img alt="Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21ZceZ5jBTL._BO2,204,203,200,35,-76_SY240.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Everyday-Things-DA-Norman/dp/0262640376"><img alt="The Design of Everyday Things" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/419AvyCIVTL._SY185.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0596517742/?tag=sollc-gb-20"><img alt="JavaScript: The Good Parts" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41bum-QsrNL._BO2,204,203,200_SY185.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html"><img alt="Don’t Make Me Think!" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/4189W8B2NXL._SY185.jpg"></a>
```

but on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sam-hasler it's rendered as:

```
            <div class=""> 
                <h3>Background</h3> 
                <div class="statement"><p><a href="http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer" rel="nofollow"></a> 
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/ASIN/0201485672" rel="nofollow"></a> 
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Everyday-Things-DA-Norman/dp/0262640376" rel="nofollow"></a> 
<a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0596517742/?tag=sollc-gb-20" rel="nofollow"></a> 
<a href="http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html" rel="nofollow"></a></p> 
</div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: I think that fancy quote in the Don't is highly suspect -- and we require a very specific order of src="" then alt="" if you're going to use <a> links.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works OK for me, confirmed on careers (although here is the same, because careers and SO have the same code paths). I think your syntax is slightly wrong, though.

[image: TEH GOGLES!]

[image: TEH GOGLES!]

```
<a href="http://google.com">
<img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" alt="TEH GOGLES!">
</a>


[![THE GOGLES!][1]][2]

[1]: https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif
[2]: http://google.com
```

Comment: That is the syntax I tried, got it wrong when typing up the question.
Do a view source on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sam-hasler and look at the Background section, there's a load of links to books there missing images. See the update on the question for what I have in edit.