# We've added a "bookshelf" to Careers 2.0 profiles -- feedback wanted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, feedback, books

We've added the ability to include books on your [Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv). The idea is to mention books that have influenced your *professional* development, and explain how they did so. Did you implement an [Observer pattern](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612) for a chat app? Did you educate your manager on the [maker's schedule](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449389554)?

We'd love to get your feedback on the functionality. Thanks!

*PS, here's a [long-ago request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26345/provide-a-programmer-bookshelf-with-your-cv) for this.*

Comment: It's working great so far :-) Nice addition!

Answer (score 4):

Bug report: apostrophe is shown as entity ref, for example *Don't Make Me Think* is `Don&#39;t Make Me Think`.

Answer (score 2):

Nice addition!

I'd like to be able to edit the title of the book however. At SO, I frequently change other people's post to correct misspelled *'ANTLR'* variations (it's all capitals, not *'Antlr'*, or *'AntLR'*, ...). When adding this book on Careers 2.0, it get displayed as *"The Definitive Antlr Reference ..."* (which is Amazon's fault, of course, but still, I'd like to correct this myself if possible).

Comment: Hi Bart, well, I think we probably don't want to make external data editable like that. A bit of a can of worms and added complexity. For the time being, we'll have to accept that the external data will be imperfect.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea, however much of the modern information is from online resources, that are not always sold in Amazon. ( Not sold in Amazon? - blasphemy :-) )

The information can be from online books, guides, blogs and etc.

If you let users add their own links, when the source is not found on Amazon, the "bookshelf" feature would be more realistic.

Comment: This would be great as a separate feature request, particularly with a description of what you would like to see happen.

Comment: I was going to take up your offer, but then I pondered on the point of having a bookshelf on a career page or CV. What is the point? :-)

Comment: @Danny: because your profile on careers isn't just to get you a job, it's where you show off everything that makes you an awesome programmer.  The books you have read and how they have influenced you are good things to know about.  They also make great talking points in an interview or social situation.

Comment: All of the interviews I have taken place in focused on achievements, abilities and knowledge, but I have never heard of someone asking about a book. The only time I have ever been asked me about books, is by newbies at a topic that want a tip for a head start. In some cases I recommended a book, in many cases I recommended a more practical approach. Not everyone reads books cover-to-cover, some people just browse through a bunch them and a multiple sites simultaneously, summing up all the knowledge with a few examples.

Comment: @Danny: Without being argumentative, your abilities and knowledge are likely related to the books you've read, as well as other sources which we do not have the ability to link on your profile yet.  That is what your original post was about.  We are still investigating ways to bring that information to our profiles and we would be happy to hear any ideas you might have.

Comment: @Danny: What I suggested was to search **all** of Amazon. Currently only a sub set called amanzon.com is searched where you only find the books available in the USA. The other Amazons are called amazon.co.uk, amazon.de, amazon.fr etc. pp.

Comment: @Martin, most books are available in amazon.com. My point was books are so 90s.

Comment: @Danny: Taking into account that one only 5% of the world population live in the US I would challenge you point that **most** books are available at amazon.com. IT books perhaps but not general literature. But even in IT books not all are written in English. Example: “Grundkurs funktionale Programmierung mit Scala” is not available on Amazon.com — it is however available on Amazon.de: http://www.amazon.de/Grundkurs-funktionale-Programmierung-mit-Scala/dp/3446420924/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1306649990&sr=8-1 . Amazon.com won't even find the book when searched by ISBN.

Comment: @Martin, I don't live in the US, but I do use Amazon as primary source for looking for books and despite being bilateral I only read professional books in English. Still, my point was not which Amazon to use, but why books.

Comment: @Danny: “only read professional books in English”: Did you know that Scala is designed at the “École polytechnique fédérale de Lausanne”. Primary language there is French. I only read professional books in English as well — 15 years ago. Times change. — And as for your other question: That is what the sourceforge, google code, git links are for. Books is just one part of it.

Comment: Those are for linking to **your** open source projects. Not everyone develops open source code.

Answer (score 0):

I already added two feedbacks before finding this threat:

[Use ISBN to search for books on careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93032/use-isbn-to-search-for-books-on-careers)

[Search more than just amazon.com for books on careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93034/search-more-then-just-amazon-com-for-books-on-careers)

Answer (score 0):

Great feature! It would be useful for me to add [leanpub](https://leanpub.com/) books as well. At the pace at which technology is currently evolving, I tend to ready books from there if available. They are the only publisher I know of offering this kind of service. Integratin via [import.io](https://import.io/)?