# Use ISBN to search for books on careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, books

In addition to Title and Author it would be nice to allow ISBN to search for book to add to careers profile. An ISBN has the distinct advantage to produce always just one hit.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Martin, this functionality is already there. You can enter either a 10-digit ISBN, or a 13-digit ISBN but be sure to remove the hyphen (eg 978-1590598382 -> 9781590598382).