# Amend the UI for adding books at careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, user-interface, books

I just inadvertantly posted a duplicate (now deleted) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93032/160382), the answer suggests that the ISBN search feature for books is already implemented.

So, could anyone modify the UI to make that clear? It currently reads

> Search for a book by title or author...

Please add *ISBN* to that to make clear this works too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISBN has been added to the prompt.  It will be live later today.