# Search more than just amazon.com for books on careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, books

True, 90% of my professional library is English. But this does not mean that the last 10% are not noteworthy. So it would be nice if you searched not just amazon**.com** for books but all of amazon (iE. Amazon**.co.uk**, amanzon**.de**amanzon**.fr**).

I take it that all amazon sites have the same web service interface so it would just be a matter a list to sited to search.

Comment: Maybe the downvoters (there must have been two) were upset by your use of the word *then* when you meant *than*. Some people are picky like that..

Comment: Well first off, you could have left this [feature-request] in the careers-feedback thread and second, you don't provide any alternative that actually allows you to scrape their inventory or has a similar backlog as Amazon. Furthermore, the Amazon bookshelf is just a 'nice-to-have' feature and shouldn't determine the quality of your CV

Comment: To be honest, I think you got your down votes from your last sentence, it's pure blind accusation and it's not welcome here. Don't make early assumption, there most probably is a good reason why it's this way.

Comment: @pavium: One could of course guess from the text that I am not a native English speaker. 
—
@Ivo Flipse: I found the careers-feedback thread **after** I wrote this question. But I can copy it across if you think that helps. I enhanced the info just as well.
—
@Myself: There was a smiley — but if you think people take offence I just remove it.

Comment: @Martin, it didn't occur to me at all. To be honest, I didn't read it carefully enough, but the error in the title was immediately obvious. I've seen much worse from native English speakers.

Comment: Additionally, note that downvotes on Meta generally indicate a *disagreement* with your feature request. People don't always leave comments *why* they disagree.

Comment: +1, some books I'd have liked to add are simply not to be found at amazon.com but at .de ...

Answer (score 4):

I agree.

However, to avoid complication, I would suggest not adding the ability to do a keyword search from all those stores, but adding a global [search by ISBN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93032/use-isbn-to-search-for-books-on-careers).

That search should query a source that can find international books as well. I assume Amazon can do this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: ISBN would be good. I consider it better then fuzzy searches in author or title.
—
Amazon behaves rather strange here. I if I put a German ISBN into amazon.com I get no result at all. If I put a US (or British or French) ISBN into amazon.de I get an “available at our partner shop” link.

I can only speculate why this is so. Do US citizen dislike being reminded that there is a world outside the US so much that amazon invests the extra work in providing an inferior search algorithm for the US?

Comment: @Martin for someone who interprets a number of downvotes as racism, you are pretty quick with using stereotypes yourself ;) It is possible that this is simply due to lack of demand - there are likely to be much, much less orders with Amazon France in the US, than vice versa. Also don't forget that ordering stuff from France or the UK to another european country is easy, while orders across the atlantic are subject to customs and therefore usually less attractive. Also, AFAIK, Amazon Europe is a separate corporate entity from Amazon.com, so there may be politics in play as well

Comment: I understand the lack of demand part. On the other hand: the algorithm for multi site search is implemented why not use on all the sites? This is of course all idle talk 2nd guessing Amazons intentions. — BTW: I worked with US programmers in Vienna. They where pretty cool guys (and galls). They also changed after being out of the US for a while, getting a broader view and better understanding of the world. So it is not in the race (I which I could edit my comment, should not have said it) but the environment US citizen live in.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did there... Linking to another feature request from the same user. Very clever.