# Add a Country Flag beside username

Tags: feature-request, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter users by country](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country)
>   [Add something like “Native language” to the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101106/add-something-like-native-language-to-the-user-profile)

Could it be possible to add a little country flag beside the username?

I'm french, and I attach great importance to spelling and conjugation.

I respect other languages, but I'm not as good at English as at French and so, I always feel compelled to apologize for my mistakes, explaining that I'm not native.

It's just a suggestion, because on the other, I suppose it could allow some natives to choose a foreign country so they don't have to make effort on spelling...

Comment: Judging from this question, your English is more than adequate. Which is a lot more than I can say for quite a few native English speakers on SO. Stop worrying that much.

Comment: And please don't apologize as part of your posts. That's only stuff we'd have to clean up. ;) Do your best and some of us are more than willing to clean up the small stuff.

Comment: @jmfsg I saw that one when I looked for a duplicate, but I think it's not really related.

Comment: @BoPersson Hadn't seen that one though. This time it's clearly related.

Comment: Honestly, if your English was inadequate (which is not the case), then we would've been able to tell. Apologizing is anything but helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit your photo and attach the flag on it. Upload it and set as Primary if you are using Gravatar.

Just like me :D

Answer (score 4):

I'm not *vehemently* opposed to this, but it does feel like clutter in the UI to me.

The *content is what matters*. As long as you try your best with your English (and use an automated spell-checker if you need one) you'll be fine: if you write interesting questions that are easy to follow except for some spelling/grammar issues there are plenty of people willing to lend a hand and edit your question. In that case it's also not necessary to apologize for any language mistakes.

Comment: I see, it's understood.